# Maximizing the global minimum of a simple parameterized trigonometric sum

Tags: mathematical-optimization, symbolic

I want to maximize the minimum of a simple (`Sin`/`Cos` based) parameterized trigonometric sum over all real values of `t`. Very simple example of this problem would be:

```
Sin[t] + Sin[t + a] + Sin[t + b]
```

It is obvious that the solution (`0 < a < b < 2 Pi`) here would be:

> {a -> 2 Pi / 3, b -> 4 Pi / 3}

I fail to produce any useful results using `Maximize`, its siblings, `ForAll` and/or `FunctionRange`.

This is just a toy example; what I really would want to do is to find these solutions to problems where individual trigonometric functions, `t` and `a`, `b`... may appear multiple times in the equation and have arbitrary constant multipliers.

**EDIT**: An example of more complicated equation would be:

```
5 Cos[a] - 3 Cos[2 t] - 3 Cos[2 (a + t)] - 3 Cos[a + 2 t] - 4 Sqrt[3] Sin[a]
```

Comment: Since you don't have any denominators in exampes shown, will this `Simplify[Reduce[D[5Cos[a] -3Cos[2t]-3Cos[2(a+t)]-3Cos[a+2t]-4Sqrt[3]Sin[a],t]==0,t],0<a<b<2Pi&&-2Pi<=t<=4Pi]` tell you all the potential candidates and you can pick and choose from them for your maxmin solution?

Comment: This is an extremely hard optimization problem. Maple finds the minimum of $\sin(t)+\sin(t+a)+\sin(t+b)$ over  $t \in [0,2\pi]$ under the restrictions on the parameters from the question, resulting in a huge expression. Maple fails with its maximization over the parameters.

Comment: Your second example can be solved by Maple which finds the minimum and then by Mathematica which finds the maximum of the minimum  $$   \left\{-3-2 \left(3 \cos \left(2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{11} \left(2 \sqrt{34}+9\right)}\right)\right)-2 \sqrt{3} \sin \left(2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{11} \left(2 \sqrt{34}+9\right)}\right)\right)\right),\left\{a\to 2 \pi -2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{11} \left(2 \sqrt{34}+9\right)}\right)\right\}\right\}$$.

Answer (score 1):

Because $f$ here is made up of trig periodic functions, I thought that taking the area squared, and then finding $a,b$ which minimizes it will work here. But I have not checked for a more general expressions that you might have. I used the range $0\to 2\pi$ for integration. You could change that as needed.

```
ClearAll[t,a,b]
expr = Sin[t] + Sin[t + a] + Sin[t + b];
expr0 = Integrate[expr^2, {t, 0, 2 Pi}] ;
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So the above is the expression to minimize. We got rid of $t$.

```
res = Minimize[expr0, {0 < a < 2 Pi, 0 < b < 2 Pi}, {a, b}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
expr /. res[[2]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Good point! I think this doesn't unfortunately work with relatively simple-looking problems I see in practice, such as `5 Cos[a] - 3 Cos[2 t] - 3 Cos[2 (a + t)] - 3 Cos[a + 2 t] - 4 Sqrt[3] Sin[a]`. Oh yes, the constant multiplier of `t` may also be zero...

Answer (score 1):

You can find global minimum in most cases with a litte trick. Since Minimize has problems working with general parameters, even if you give conditions, insert known constants for parameters and generalize later.

But in all cases you have to test whether you miss branch cuts with the inserted constant number. Try different mumbers.

Let me begin with your second example with one parameter first.

```
sum1[t_, a_] = 
   5 Cos[a] - 3 Cos[2 t] - 3 Cos[2 (a + t)] - 3 Cos[a + 2 t] - 
   4 Sqrt[3] Sin[a];

min[a_] = 
  Minimize[{sum1[t, a], 0 < t < 2 Pi} /. a -> E, t] /. E -> a // 
     FullSimplify[#, 0 < a < 2 Pi] &
```

[image]

```
Plot[min[a][[1]], {a, 0, 2 Pi}, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image]

```
nmin[a_?NumericQ] := NMinimize[{sum1[t, a], 0 < t < 2 Pi}, t]

Plot[nmin[a][[1]], {a, 0, 2 Pi}, GridLines -> Automatic]

Maximize[{min[a][[1]], 0 < a < 2 Pi}, a] // FullSimplify

(*   {4, {a -> 2 (\[Pi] - ArcTan[2/Sqrt[3]])}}   *)
```

For the first example with two paramters you can find global minimum, but following maximization needs some help.

```
sum2 = Sin[t] + Sin[a + t] + Sin[b + t];

cond1 = 0 < a < 2 Pi && 0 < b < 2 Pi;
cond2 = 0 < t < 2 Pi;

min2[a_, b_] = 
  Minimize[{sum2 /. {a -> E, b -> EulerGamma} // TrigExpand, cond2}, 
t] /. Reverse /@ {a -> E, b -> EulerGamma} // Simplify

(*   {2 Cos[b/2] Sin[
1/2 (b - 
   4 ArcTan[(
     Sqrt[3 + 2 Cos[a] + 2 Cos[a - b] + 2 Cos[b]] +  Sin[a] + 
      Sin[b])/(1 + Cos[a] + Cos[b])])] + 
 Sin[a - 2 ArcTan[(
  Sqrt[3 + 2 Cos[a] + 2 Cos[a - b] + 2 Cos[b]] + Sin[a]  + 
   Sin[b])/(1 + Cos[a] + Cos[b])]], {t -> 
 2 (\[Pi] - 
  ArcTan[(Sqrt[3 + 2 Cos[a] + 2 Cos[a - b] + 2 Cos[b]] + Sin[a] + 
    Sin[b])/(1 + Cos[a] + Cos[b])])}}   *)

Plot3D[min2[a, b][[1]], {a, 0, 2  Pi}, {b, 0, 2 Pi},   PlotPoints -> 50,
 Mesh -> {Range[0, 2 Pi, Pi/3], Range[0, 2 Pi, Pi/3]}, 
 Ticks -> {Range[0, 2 Pi, Pi/3], Range[0, 2 Pi, Pi/3], Automatic}
 ]
```

[image]

Maximize does not succed maximizing min2 over a and b. do your own examinations. You get maxima where the argument of the ArcTan jumps from positive to negative, that is where

```
Reduce[Sqrt[3 + 2 Cos[a] + 2 Cos[a - b] + 2 Cos[b]] == 0 && 
  1 + Cos[a] + Cos[b] == 0 && cond1, {a, b}]

(*   (a == (2 \[Pi])/3 && b == (4 \[Pi])/3) || (a == (4 \[Pi])/3 && 
b == (2 \[Pi])/3)   *)

Limit[min2[2/3 Pi, b][[1]], b -> 4/3 Pi]

(*   0   *)

NMaximize[{min2[a, b][[1]], cond1}, {{a, 0, Pi}, b}]

(*   {3.42832*10^-8, {a -> 2.0944, b -> 4.18879}}   *)

NMaximize[{min2[a, b][[1]], cond1}, {{a, Pi, 2 Pi}, b}]

(*   {8.82174*10^-9, {a -> 4.18879, b -> 2.0944}}   *)
```

Comment: To put it mildly, the trick  /. a -> E, t] /. E -> a in min[a_] = 
  Minimize[{sum1[t, a], 0 < t < 2 Pi} /. a -> E, t] /. E -> a // 
     FullSimplify[#, 0 < a < 2 Pi] & is very doubtful.

Comment: As i mentioned, you have to test with numerical methods, whether it is valid.

Comment: In a lot of cases it works fine.